# What is the best approach to query and return relationship?

Tags: sql

I'm very new to SQL and like to how to tackle the following problem. Thanks in advance!

I have a table with 2 columns, OldProductLineID and its respective NewProductLineID.

How do I return a table with 1 additional column (3rd column) to show the relationship between the ProductLineIDs

**Sample Data**

```
OldID | NewID  
123   | 987  
234   | 987  
456   | 876  
456   | 877  
567   | 777
```

**Outcome I need**

```
OldID | NewID | Relationship    
123   | 987   | Regroup  
234   | 987   | Regroup  
456   | 876   | Split  
456   | 877   | Split  
567   | 777   | Rebrand
```

In the above scenario,
1) OldID 123 and 234 were regrouped as NewID 987.
2) OldID 456 was split to NewID 876 and 877.
3) OldID 567 was re-branded as NewID 777

Thanks again!

Comment: what database you are using? Put some sample data also

Comment: Thanks. Added in Sample data to illustrate the question.

Comment: You forgot to mention the *relationship* between `oldID, newID` and `Relationship`.

Comment: oops. ok. added too.

Comment: Is this all? You have only 5 rows in your table and you want a 3d column with hardcoded values?

Comment: I've have a few thousands IDs and would like to establish their relationships. Correct, I want a 3rd column and I think hardcoded values should be fine. Thanks.

Comment: What I'm trying to understand with all these questions and you still don't make it clear is **why** you want `Regroup` for the first 2 lines, `Split` for the next 2 and `Rebrand` for the last. This is something that you understand but don't expect us to guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just by guessing your requirement and it works regardless of the dbms you are using:

```
select 
  t.OldID, t.NewID,
  case
    when exists (
      select 1 from tablename
      where newid = t.newid and oldid <> t.oldid
    ) then 'Regroup' 
    when exists (
      select 1 from tablename
      where newid <> t.newid and oldid = t.oldid
    ) then 'Split'
    else 'Rebrand'
  end Relationship
from tablename t
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d8b6dcbc0995173d3f47878ad3b16b2e)

Comment: Wow. This work perfectly. Thanks. Will go find out how your code work, especially what is "when exists" and "select 1".

Comment: Read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 2):

You can use `COUNT()` `OVER PARTITION BY` like following. It should work for most of the databases.

```
SELECT oldid, 
       newid, 
       CASE 
         WHEN s = 1 
              AND r > 1 THEN 'Regroup' 
         WHEN r = 1 
              AND s > 1 THEN 'Split' 
         WHEN r = 1 
              AND s = 1 THEN 'Rebrand' 
         ELSE 'Wrong Data(Mix)' 
       END AS 'Relationship' 
FROM   (SELECT *, 
               Count(*) OVER(partition BY oldid) s, 
               Count(*) OVER(partition BY newid) r 
        FROM   [yourtablename]) t 
ORDER  BY oldid
```

I have created a sample in `SQL Server`, which you can check here  [Online Demo in SQL Server](https://rextester.com/GJM80215)

**Output**

```
+-------+-------+--------------+
| OldId | NewId | Relationship |
+-------+-------+--------------+
| 123   | 987   | Regroup      |
+-------+-------+--------------+
| 234   | 987   | Regroup      |
+-------+-------+--------------+
| 456   | 876   | Split        |
+-------+-------+--------------+
| 456   | 877   | Split        |
+-------+-------+--------------+
| 567   | 777   | Rebrand      |
+-------+-------+--------------+
```